# Spring: Accessing environmental variable from an AbstractBeanDefinitionParser

Tags: spring

I have an `AbstractBeanDefinitionParser` and I'd like to inject a variable with `@Value("${my.var}")` or to get this value directly from `org.springframework.core.env.Environment`.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I can obtain this from `parseContext`.

```
Environment environment = parserContext.getReaderContext().getEnvironment();
```